# Delete duplicate rows based on condition in another column

Tags: r

Let's say I have this data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(NA,6,6,8),
  x= c(1,2,2,4),
  y = c(NA,2,NA,NA),
  z = c("apple", 2, "2", NA), 
  d = c(NA, 5, 5, 5),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Rows 2 and 3 are duplicates and row 3 has an NA value. I want to delete the duplicate row with the NA value so that it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  a = c(NA,6,8),
  x= c(1,2,4),
  y = c(NA,2,NA),
  z = c("apple", 2, NA), 
  d = c(NA, 5, 5),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  
df2 <- df %>% group_by (a,x,z,d) %>% filter(y == max(y))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>%
   arrange_all() %>%
   filter(!duplicated(fill(., everything())))
   a x  y     z  d
1 NA 1 NA apple NA
2  6 2  2     2  5
3  8 4 NA  <NA>  5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% arrange(a,x,z,d) %>% distinct(a,x,z,d,.keep_all=TRUE)

   a x  y     z  d
1  6 2  2     2  5
2  8 4 NA  <NA>  5
3 NA 1 NA apple NA
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Fill `NA` values with previous non-NA and select unique rows with `distinct`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% fill(everything()) %>% distinct()

#   a x  y     z  d
#1 NA 1 NA apple NA
#2  6 2  2     2  5
#3  8 4 NA  <NA>  5
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to do it without fill and distinct? Something with group_by or filter?

Comment: `group_by` would not work directly since `NA` could be in any column and not only `y` and they have different values. You can use `df %>%  fill(everything()) %>% group_by(across()) %>% slice(1L)`